# Clipboard Copy with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want that when my users clicks on a link who is near to a text box, the content of the text box gets copied to the clipboard. How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript